# What's the correct way to set the nginx's proxy configuration for Beego?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04, nginx-config, beego

In a PC with Ubuntu 18.04.1 Server Edition I'm developing a web page for which I registered a domain name.
In order to pass from http to https I'm trying to use the let's encrypt service https://letsencrypt.org/

I temporary disabled the firewalls both in the Ubuntu 18.04.02 Desktop laptop I'm using to connect to the PC:
riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~$ sudo ufw status
[sudo] password for riccardo:
Status: inactive

and in Ubuntu 18.04.01 Server PC where I'm developing my web page:

marco@pc01:~$ sudo ufw status
[sudo] password for marco:
Status: inactive

When executing the command to get the certificate:

```
marco@pc01:~/go/src/MyPage$ sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w /home/marco/go/src/MyPage -d ggc.world -d www.ggc.world
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for ggc.world
http-01 challenge for www.ggc.world
Using the webroot path /home/marco/go/src/MyPage for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. www.ggc.world (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from
http://www.ggc.world/.well-known/acme-challenge/Gu8UD5QRmXl5pp2fJX1c3Qc3pAK_gP-cpuZA0tTaAi8 [109.116.160.164]: "<html>\n<head>\n  <title>404 Not  
Found</title>\n</head>\n<body bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">\n  <h2>404 Not Found</h2>\n  <p></p>\n</body>\n</html>", ggc.world (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:
unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://ggc.world/.well-known/acme-challenge/gGMNXHbKyuSyV_WZ-
z7NghdqamkU6YCzNVeohBOrtn0 [109.116.160.164]: "<html>\n<head>\n  <title>404 Not Found</title>\n</head>\n<body bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">\n  <h2>404 Not 
Found</h2>\n  <p></p>\n</body>\n</html>"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.ggc.world
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.ggc.world/.well-known/acme-challenge/Gu8UD5QRmXl5pp2fJX1c3Qc3pAK_gP-cpuZA0tTaAi8
   [109.116.160.164]: "<html>\n<head>\n  <title>404 Not
   Found</title>\n</head>\n<body bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">\n  <h2>404 Not
   Found</h2>\n  <p></p>\n</body>\n</html>"

   Domain: ggc.world
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://ggc.world/.well-known/acme-challenge/gGMNXHbKyuSyV_WZ-z7NghdqamkU6YCzNVeohBOrtn0
   [109.116.160.164]: "<html>\n<head>\n  <title>404 Not
   Found</title>\n</head>\n<body bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">\n  <h2>404 Not
   Found</h2>\n  <p></p>\n</body>\n</html>"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

The Community Leader in the Let's Encrypt forum asserts that my nginx's proxy configuration doesn't work, because may be it's buggy.

As Golang's MVC framework I'm using Beego.
As far as I can see in the available information online and in some books, proxy configuration within nginx’s default.conf is the only way to use NGINX as webserver for Beego:
- https://beego.me/docs/deploy/nginx.md
- taken from Go Web Development Cookbook: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wUA_Yjh2MrCCqS9rGnITtBzm00Zum2II
- taken from Nginx Cookbook (2017) :
    - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xO0fNg9JOHz4vh94EHd4FTs_hBjJAiqb
    - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bXTcSmA5ib57HppOujaTtjlTLmE85pp2

```
marco@pc01:~$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.15.12
```

This is my /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf  :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name ggc.world www.ggc.world;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.7:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

So... my question is:
what's the correct way to set the nginx's proxy configuration for Beego, in order to use nginx as the web server for Beego?

Here you can find the /var/log/letsencrypt.log file: 
[letsencrypt.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L1nJGtqJidIcoega50hWZhAo0479Fmfr)

Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco

Comment: so are you looking for help with Let's Encrypt or Proxying to Beego?

Comment: According to Let's Encrypt Community Leader I should seek help for proxying with Beego, which in turn will help in let's encrypt.

Comment: if you just want to serve static files with Let's Encrypt,  try this tiny server <100 lines of code  https://go-www.com/

Comment: @nbari Thank you very much for the link to go-www.com. It's a very interesting project, but as far as I understood it's useful only for static files server. But I'm developing a "full-fledged" server, with a static part, but with also a dynamic part.

Comment: use supervisor.